# Automorphism of $ℚ[\sqrt{d}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I came across this line from class note: $\mathrm{Aut}(ℚ[\sqrt{d}]) = \{1, σ\}$. I understand all the terms separately: “$\mathrm{Aut}$” stands for automorphism which means bijective homomorphism into itself, “$ℚ[\sqrt{d}]$” is complex number of $\sqrt{d}$, “$σ$” refers to conjugate.

To the best of my understanding, the line reads "Automorphism of complex number $ℚ[\sqrt{d}]$ is either $1$ or $σ$." How do you translate this line intuitively, especially about the $1$? Any explanation would be much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: $ℚ[√d] = \{a + b√d;\; a, b ∈ ℚ\}$ is a subfield of $ℂ$, and this statement reads: *There are two field automorphisms $ℚ[√d] → ℚ[√d]$, viz: the identity $1 = \mathrm{id}$, and some other automorphism $σ$.* As it turns out, $σ$ is not the complex conjugation in general, but the conjugation of $√d$, sending $a+b√d$ to $a-b√d$.

Comment: @k.stm: Thanks and now I understand: 1 stands for identity function and “$σ$” stands for conjugating function which still returns the complex number. Thanks again.

Comment: @k.stm: You should make your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so this my comment again:

---

$ℚ[√d]=\{a+b√d;\; a,b∈Q\}$ is a subfield of C, and this statement reads: There are two field automorphisms $ℚ[√d]→ ℚ[√d]$, viz: the identity $1=id$, and some other automorphism $σ$. As it turns out, $σ$ is not the complex conjugation in general, but the conjugation of $√d$, sending $a+b√d$ to $a−b√d$.